# How to print high quality with Gimp or Libre Office Draw and Canon Pixma ix6810?

Tags: printing, libreoffice, canon, gimp

I understand Ubuntu 16.04 comes with native drivers for Canon Pixma ix6810, I can print but with very low quality. Supposedly I installed Gutenprint but printings are still ugly.
With other computer with Ubuntu 16.04 and a low cost HP printer I can print pretty decently.
Am I missing anything, like wrong Gutenprint installation or a missing CUPS file?

Answer (score 0):

Canon supply drivers for this printer; (it is part of the ix6800series):

go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100586302.html and click to download and SAVE what will be cnijfilter-ix6800series-4.10-1-deb.tar.gz

Then open a terminal; and copy each line of command; and paste into the terminal; hitting the ENTER key after each paste;

then move onto the next line (to paste into the terminal, right-click at the text prompt: the flashing sign; and look for PASTE in the menu that appears ...)

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf cnijfilter-ix6800series-4.10-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter-ix6800series-4.10-1-deb
```

then run the install script; watch the terminal as it may ask you questions ..

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

Let us know if the Canon driver gives better results;

---

the other option for you; for a really fine printer like you; is to install TurboPrint http://www.turboprint.info/printer_Canon_PIXMA_iX6800series.html

their product supplies very high quality drivers